# "Show full text" links in live chat no longer expand and instead redirects to the raw data

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat, hyperlinks

When someone sends a large amount of a text as a single message in chat, it normally comes up with a 'show full text' link which lets you expand the message so you can see it in it's entirety.

Instead in the last few days it's linking to a page where I'm shown the text, unformatted at all.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40422152#40422152 -- is the original message, interestingly in the transcript the 'show full text' is still working correctly however in the live chat it takes you to:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/118/40422152

I've only noticed this happening in the Super User chat, but that maybe just because I'm not active in many others. I'm using chrome, and others have reported the same issue.

My current version of chrome is: `Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

This happens at home on both my linux, and windows (10) machine (the above version is from my windows machine, I'll add my linux machine when I get to check it.) I also believe it happens on my windows 10 machine at work which has no/minimal add-ins (I'll check exactly what it has when I'm next in).

I auth via google auth, and I've tried logging out and back in also.

Comment: No repro, even in the same room you mentioned. Something on your side probably, e.g. userscript. There are some popular scripts (e.g. SOUP) that many people got, might cause such problems. To verify this, use a different, clean, browser, without any user scripts/extensions/plugins.

Comment: I have this issue at work with no add ons

Comment: No repro same Chrome version, Win 7.

Comment: @djsmiley2k Maybe you have an internet issue that is also causing your posts to appear twice?

Comment: @DavidPostill nah that was posted from a park this afternoon, on my phone, with bad reception.

Comment: Don't know if it matters, win 10 on both the systems I've seen it happen on.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Happens to me too, even without any extensions. Latest chrome.

Comment: Okay wait... issue not present in chrome in incognito... huh.

Comment: No repro, Chrome latest both Windows 7 and 10, logged in or Incognito. /cc @rahuldottech

Comment: @rahuldottech are you using google auth to login? I know I am. I'm going to try fully logging out and back in. I do recall now that some sites showing me logged out, when I was definately already logged in (SE and AskUbuntu iirc) however I presumed this was just something odd going on.

Comment: I've double checked and it also happens in the bridge, making me think it's not something specific to root access.

Comment: Should have asked before, do you get any client side errors when clicking the link? (In Chrome, open its developer tools and see Console and Network tabs.)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yeah, got about four 500 server errors from yahooapis

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd djsmiley2k and I have determined that it was the PorkChat extension thingy. Let's all raid Fredley's house

Comment: @rahuldottech Well, that's the first thing I asked. Too bad it's so hard to even know what extensions you have and how to disable them. Guess next time I can say for sure "You have some funky extension causing it", without even bothering to ask.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd lol you don't seem to understand 'be nice'.

Comment: I am nice, but when people don't listen to what I tell I get annoyed. I'm human. And all those user scripts are just annoying in my opinion, with the tons of "bugs" they cause (which people then blame SE for, of course), but that's not your fault. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm sorryyyyyyyyyy. My bad.

Comment: @rahuldottech buy me 2 beers and all will be forgotten... ;-) 